# error read data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, read-data

i have an applicataion that must to read data from database. i think it simple but why i still got error like this :

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: views/detail_usulan.php

i have tried to repair this code but its still cant work. i'll show u my code. i need your help:(

My controller :

```
function detail_usulan(){
        $data = array('model_usulan' => $this->model_usulan->get_all());
        //$this->load->view('usulan/detail_usulan', $data);
        $this->render('usulan/detail_usulan', $data);
}
```

My models :

```
class model_usulan extends MY_Model{
    function get_all(){
        return $this->db->get('usulan_rkau');
    }
}
```

My view :

```
<?php foreach ($data as $view_data) { ?>
            <tr>
            <th> Tahun : </th>
            <td><?php echo $view_data->tahun; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Did you try any of the answers?

Comment: Does the function `$this->model_usulan->get_all` return an array which has data as a key?  If not, your issue is going to be with the load view part, it would need to be `$this->load->view('usulan/detail_usulan', ['data' => $data]);`, as that's what sets up the variable naming in the views.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try it like below on controller instead of it begin in an array()

```
$data['model_usulan'] = $this->model_usulan->get_all();

$this->load->view('usulan/detail_usulan', $data);
```

> On your view change this $data

```
<?php foreach ($data as $view_data) { ?>
   <tr>
      <th> Tahun : </th>
      <td><?php echo $view_data->tahun; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php }?>
```

> To $model_usulan in the array

```
<?php foreach ($model_usulan as $view_data) { ?>
   <tr>
      <th> Tahun : </th>
      <td><?php echo $view_data->tahun; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php }?>
```

> **Note:**  Your class name and file name should have the **FIRST** letter upper case **ONLY** same applies for controllers and libraries etc

As explained here [Classnames](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming) And [Filenames](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

Filename: Model_usulan.php

```
<?php

class Model_usulan extends CI_Model {

}
```

> Also On your model function try

```
return $this->db->get('usulan_rkau')->result();
```

Or

```
$query = $this->db->get('usulan_rkau');

return $query->result();
```

And may be change this

```
MY_Model {
```

To

```
CI_Model {
```

Comment: thankyou for your help, but its still cant work. they said that the variabel undefined :( @wolfgang1983

Comment: undefined what variable?

Comment: On your view did you change it to $model_usulan like what said

Comment: variable undefined model_usulan, yes i have changed it. but still cant work @wolfgang1983

Comment: It could be something to do with your render

Comment: or just try like `$data['model_usulan'] = $this->model_usulan->get_all();`  instead of beign in the array

Comment: Did you also do i like in model because you did not use a result or a result_array()  other wise it must be with your render. Not much else can help you with

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this change in your controller

```
function detail_usulan(){
    $data['data'] = array('model_usulan' => $this->model_usulan->get_all());
    $this->load->view('usulan/detail_usulan', $data);
    //$this->render('usulan/detail_usulan', $data);
}
```

or

change in your view

```
 foreach ($model_usulan as $view_data) {
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: thankyou for your help, but its still cant work. they said that the variabel undefined :( @DilipPatel

Comment: i've tried both of them but still error  @Dilip Patel

Comment: if you are using render method the you need to use 
    $this->template->write_view('data', $data);    
    $this->template->render();
and if you are using load->view method then you can direct pass $data
   $this->load->view('usulan/detail_usulan', $data);